# sharing 1 ajax repsonse between controllers

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

The big picture is - I am tyring to get an ajax call to fire in one place and send to all my controllers (there are about 8) and based on the string answer set a show/hide in all of them. It seems pretty simple but I am having some trouble working the kinks out. I was able to figuire out how to shre a json object between 2 controllers but this is a little bit different so I'm thinking that maybe I'm applying the previous logic that worked for me in an incorrect way.

I set up a factory to share between all the controllers like so

```
.factory('statusCheck', ['$http', function ($http) {

var currentId = self.location.search;
if(currentId[0] === "?"){
    currentId = currentId.slice(1);
}
 var stats = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/getLessonDetails/" + currentId
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){

    return data.status;
    });

return stats;

}])
```

All I am trying to do here is have it do the ajax call (you can ignore the currentId part) and return the data.status. In each controller I then inject statusCheck and use it.

Once I have statusCheck coming back as the right string value (the data.status will equal 1 of 3 strings) I want to use it in the controller to show/hide stuff.  I already have a scope boolean set up in each controller called $scope.editorEnabled that toggles between the show/hides I want (if set to true or false.

So once I have the statusCheck in the controller I want to check its value and do something like this in the controller -

```
 if(statusCheck == "On"){
 $scope.editorEnabled = true;
 }else if(statusCheck == "Off"){
  $scope.editorEnabled = false;
 }else if(statusCheck == "ViewOnly"){
   $scope.editorEnabled = false;
   $scope.viewOnlyMode= true;
 }
```

I don't know if my factory is even working correctly, but when it does I want to make sure I get the ajax get's the string before it tries to read these if statements in the controller, because they are not wrapped in anything and will immediately fire. I don't know if this thinking is good for angular, I am still adjusting myself to it's process. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: `$http` returns a promise , so that is what you are returning from factory... use `.then()` to access data in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a property in your factory returning service when the http promise is resolved and watch for the property to change in your controller;

```
.factory('statusCheck', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var me = {
        status: 0
    };

    var currentId = self.location.search;
    if(currentId[0] === "?"){
      currentId = currentId.slice(1);
    }

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/getLessonDetails/" + currentId
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
       me.status = data.status;
    });

    return me;
}]);
```

and in your controller, watch for statusCheck.status to change and do whatever you want

```
 $scope.statusCheck = statusCheck;

 $scope.$watch('statusCheck.status', function (newValue) {
       if(newValue == "On"){
          $scope.editorEnabled = true;
       }else if(newValue == "Off"){
          $scope.editorEnabled = false;
       }else if(newValue == "ViewOnly"){
         $scope.editorEnabled = false;
         $scope.viewOnlyMode= true;
       }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer, there are three approaches you can take:-

1. Inject your factory into each controller and expose the status to the view.
2. As 1, but add a $watch if there is additional processing that the controller must do (doesn't sound like it from your question)
3. Use $emit to broadcast a change

My guess is that 1, which is the simplest, will do the job for you

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you need to use .then():

```
statusCheck.then(function (status) {
    if (status == "On") { ... }
    // the rest of your code
});
```